# how to send link that leads directly to the relevant page?

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oracle-apex, apex, oracle-apex-5.1

i got a question, there is button in my page and it sends a email to customer and says you need to select your plan.

I want to send a email with a link that leads directly to the page where the customer will select the plan. If the application is already logged in, the link should go directly to that page, if the application is not open, it should go to the login screen first, and go to the same page immediately after logging in.

i donot know it is so easy or not,  i researched some blogs and forum or i could not find the answer

Comment: Did you read this? https://forums.oracle.com/ords/apexds/post/direct-page-access-via-an-email-link-8236

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, You can do this by following below steps.

```
1. design your mail template/mail body along with link to your application Plan selection page.

2. Apex - enable deep link in your application.
```

So, this case if the user opened the Application already, it directly go the respective plan selection page, else it will show the login page, Once login system will directly open the Plan page.

Hope this will helpful.